# How can I include VAT to product price in Google Data Feeds?

Tags: datafeed

Few days ago, Google has suspended my Google Merchant Center Account due to VAT issue. The products price on Google Shopping don't match with my website's landing pages. On my site, the price are VAT exclusive. But Google policy wants me to include the VAT. But problem is my VAT depends on the country chosen by the customer. So one can not add it in advance as a fixed amount. They wrote following in their email to me:

`Inaccurate prices (due to value-added tax (VAT) related issues) 
We found that for many of your items, the price as submitted in your product data is not in compliance with our feed specifications on the ‘price’ attribute. Please update your product data and the corresponding landing pages on your website to ensure that the specified price is inclusive of any applicable taxes such as value-added tax (VAT).`

So how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Prices in Google products feed must include VAT for target country (except US, Canada, India). If you are selling to more countries, you should add more feeds in your Google Merchant Center with different target country.

Comment: Ok that's fine, but how to add VAT in `<g:price></g:price>`?

Comment: Just specify price incl. VAT. If price excl. VAT is 100 EUR and VAT is 20%, use <g:price>120 EUR</g:price>

Comment: But mine case is different. VAT depends on the country chosen by the customer. It varies for all countries. Same is true for shipping cost. I'm confused how to configure all these? Please help me on it. Thanks.

Comment: Google product feed is connected to specified country, so you should maybe create separate feeds for every country and specify some parameter in URL which will cause that product price will be shown with correct VAT for that country. Google is checking if price defined in <g:price> is same as price found on URL provided in merchant feed tag <link>.